# Create Facebook event as Page with rGraph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an event on Facebook on behalf of the page i own with Graph API. 
From FB documentation i read that it is done like this:

POSTing `name` and `start_time` (other things are optional) to 
https://graph.facebook.com/{Page_ID}/events

with proper premissions (`create_event`, `manage_pages`)

playing around with this in Graph API Explorer i do get event created but it is done under my own profile rather than Page.

So is it possible to create the event under the Page i own rather than my profile?

PS i double checked the page id so it is not my profile id

PPS I know there are allready many discussions about this here, but unfortunatley i couldnt find a straightforward answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured this out myself.  I needed to post it with page access token. heres the code

```
$page_info = $this->fb->api('/' . $page_id . '?fields=access_token');
if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {

$path = realpath(APPPATH . '../path/to/img');
$args = array(
    'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
    'start_time' => $start_time,
    'description' => $description
    'name' => $name,
    'location' => $loaction
);
$img = 'img.jpg';
if ($upload) {// if picture is needed
    $args['@' . $img] = '@' . $path . '/' . $img;

    $this->fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
}

$res = $this->fb->api("/" . $this->input->post('fb_event'), "post", $args); // should give back event id        
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually help anyone who needs it, because the code you post doesn't give enough insight.